# Building MonoDevelop v7.0.0 on Ubuntu 16.04, with Mono 5.0

Tags: ubuntu, msbuild, mono, monodevelop

Please can you help building MonoDevelop 7 on Ubuntu 16.04
This version needs msbuild 15 to build.

I have built OK, mono-5.0.0.78, which seems to have msbuild 15 incorporated.

But monodevelop-7.0.0.2943 does not build. and fails with following, but i don't know how to resolve. "xbuild" is now deprecated in favour of "msbuild" 15

MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin'.
WARNING: Error reading msbuild project information, ensure that your input solution or project file is valid. NETCore and UAP projects will be skipped, only packages.config files will be restored.

All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
msbuild /t:Restore /p:RestoreDisableParallel=true external/RefactoringEssentials/RefactoringEssentials.2017/RefactoringEssentials.csproj
/bin/bash: msbuild: command not found

Comment: Have you installed the msbuild package? I suspect it is not included with the Mono package by default.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Try to do the following:

1. Add the mono-project.com repositories to your Ubuntu: see http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin
2. `sudo apt-get install mono-devel`